# Unnestling a dictionary into a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I am downloading financial data, that comes in dictionaries within lists in Python looking like this:

```
[{'complete': True,
  'volume': 2,
  'time': '2004-05-31T21:00:00.000000000Z',
  'mid': {'o': '6.07260', 'h': '6.07260', 'l': '6.07260', 'c': '6.07260'}},
 {'complete': True,
  'volume': 2,
  'time': '2004-06-01T21:00:00.000000000Z',
  'mid': {'o': '6.08790', 'h': '6.08790', 'l': '6.08790', 'c': '6.08790'}}]
```

I have quite a few million such datapoints, that I would want into Pandas.

So far, I have used the following code:

```
    v = []
    for keys in [x.split(":") for x in m.keys()]:
        _v = r.get(keys[0])
        for k in keys[1:]:
            _v = _v.get(k)
        v.append(_v)

    return v

record_converter = convrec if conv is None else conv
column_map_ohlcv = OrderedDict([
   ('time', 'Date'),
   ('mid:o', 'Open'),
   ('mid:h', 'High'),
   ('mid:l', 'Low'),
   ('mid:c', 'Close'),
   ('volume', 'Volume')
])
cmap = column_map_ohlcv if colmap is None else colmap
df = pd.DataFrame([list(record_converter(rec, cmap)) for rec in r.get('candles')])
df.columns = list(cmap.values())
```

It works, but it is not very fast, as I need to split the 'mid' into different columns?

Is there some more direct way of getting it into a dataframe without using looping? As in for example using numpy or pandas to do the heavy lifting?

The desired outcome should be a Pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
Date                    Open    High    Low     Close   Volum

2004-05-31 21:00:00    6.0726   6.0726  6.0726  6.0726  2
2004-06-01 21:00:00    6.0879   6.0879  6.0879  6.0879  2
```

Comment: Could you specify your desired outcome?

Comment: What kind of file is that? A binary or a plaintext file? I think it's easier to preprocess it and just strip out all the redundant information (i.e., the dictionaries). There is no reason why this file is not simply a csv file form the snippet you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work (your input list is called `l`):

```
tempdf = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

which yields

```
   complete                                                mid                            time  volume
0      True  {'o': '6.07260', 'h': '6.07260', 'l': '6.07260...  2004-05-31T21:00:00.000000000Z       2
1      True  {'o': '6.08790', 'h': '6.08790', 'l': '6.08790...  2004-06-01T21:00:00.000000000Z       2
```

Now you can split the dictionary in `mid` into several columns and use `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([tempdf.drop('mid', axis=1), tempdf['mid'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

which gives the desired outcome:

```
   complete                            time  volume        o        h        l        c
0      True  2004-05-31T21:00:00.000000000Z       2  6.07260  6.07260  6.07260  6.07260
1      True  2004-06-01T21:00:00.000000000Z       2  6.08790  6.08790  6.08790  6.08790
```

Answer (score 0):

use pandas function instead it will be faster and simple. For example it can be good staring point. I added renaming indexes and pivot to make Close, High, Low, Open columns if it is necessary:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'complete': True,
 'volume': 2,
 'time': '2004-05-31T21:00:00.000000000Z',
 'mid': {'o': '6.07260', 'h': '6.07260', 'l': '6.07260', 'c': '6.07260'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.rename(index={'o': 'Open', 'h': 'High', 'l': 'Low', 'c': 'Close'}, inplace=True)
df['column'] = df.index

df = pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['column'], index=['complete', 'time', 'volume'], values=['mid'], aggfunc=np.sum)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)
```

Comment: That is one of the items out of millions of items in a list. So to achieve that, I need to iterate thru the list that contains the nested dictionaries, and hence it will be very slow.

Comment: @Terjeja If you want to move Open, High etc to separate column try to use pivot function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html#pandas.pivot if you will have errors for duplicated data use pivot_table function instead with average

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that will increase the speed, as I would have to iterate thru the pivot-function a few million times. Or am I missing something?